# How do I check the answer to polynomial long division in $\mathbb{Z}_7$?

Tags: field-theory

The question that I was given on my homework was to find $q(x)$ and $r(x)$ that satisfy:
$f(x)=g(x)q(x)+r(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_7$ where $f(x)=x^6 +3x^5 +4x^2 -3x +2$ and $g(x)= 3x^2 +2x-3$. I think that I did everything correctly. However, my question is about checking my answer.

If I plug $g(x)q(x)+r(x)$ in WolframAlpha and then reduce the coefficients mod $7$ after will I necessarily get $f(x)$ if I did my math correctly?

Comment: Yes. To make sure the answer is correct, that and $\deg r<\deg g$ will do.

Comment: My advice to you is to do the remultiplication by hand, not using Wolfram. Experience and skill in using pencil and paper is more valuable than you may think. If you work directly in $\Bbb F_7$, the computation will not be at all hard. (You need only know that the powers of $3$ are $1,3,2,6,4,5,1$, and think of this list as a log table for multiplication.